# Event Listeners no funcionan, ¿por qué?

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo problemas con mi código: el código html es de un formulario, pero el botón es lo único visible, y el formulario aparece al darle click al botón, pero al darle click nunca sale y no pasa nada.
Alguien puede ayudarme por favor...

```
        <button class="signUp btn">Contactanos</button>

        <div class="form-modal">
            <div class="content-wrapper">
                <div class="close"> + </div>
                <img src="img/profile.jpg" alt="">
                <form action="enviar.php" method="POST">
                    <input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre">
                    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Correo">
                    <input type="text" name="telefono" placeholder="Telefono">
                    <textarea name="mensaje" id="mensaje" placeholder="mensaje"></textarea>
                    <button class="submit btn">Enviar</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Y estos son los scripts que no me funcionan

```
const singUp = document.querySelector(".signUp");
const modal = document.querySelector(".form-modal");
const close = document.querySelector(".close");

singUp.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
    modal.style.display = "flex";
})

close.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
    modal.style.display = "none";
})
```

Comment: Yo lo probe y funciona, es decir, al hacer clic en el botón, aparece el formulario y al hacer clic en "cerrar" desaparece. ¿Que error te muestra en consola o en pantalla?. Saludos.

Comment: por lo que entendi no te estaria funcionando el boton de enviar, creo q es por que no estas llamando a la clase btn y falta el atributo type="submit", fijate si funciona asi!

Comment: Hola, En la consola del navegador solo me dice: "no even listeners"

Comment: Seguramente tienes el código _javascript_ arriba, antes de crear los elementos HTML. Colócalo hasta abajo, antes de `</body>` y ya no deberías tener problemas.

Comment: Hola @DavidTorres. Lo puedes hacer como dice Triby o también agregando el atributo `defer` o `async` si lo colocas entre las etiquetas `<head></head>`para que se cargue de forma **diferida** o **asíncrona** y así no tendrás problemas. Lo probé y todo el código está bien.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error que presentas en tus comentarios se debe a cómo llamas los scripts. Dado que no es una función, sino, que estás añadiendo oyentes y variables en el cuerpo, es posible que estés intentando acceder a una etiqueta que aún no existe.

Si el script está siendo llamado en el **< Head >** este error es común, deberías mover tus **< script >** después del **< Body >**. Eso arreglaría en parte el problema que comunicas, el resto parece estar muy normal.

La razón es:

```
const singUp = document.querySelector(".signUp"); // undefined
const modal = document.querySelector(".form-modal"); // undefined
const close = document.querySelector(".close"); // undefined
```

No existen tales etiquetas, en el momento en que son llamadas.

[Si buscas un código con solución directa, este es. (En inglés).](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17717175/simple-event-listener-not-working-js/17717239)

Comment: Tu respuesta es muy interesante, sería conveniente que agregues el código y explicación traducida directamente en lugar del enlace para que sea una solución completa.

Answer (score 0):

Parece ser que lo que no te esta funcionando es debido al orden de carga de tus scripts.

El orden en el que vas a cargar tus scripts es importante, si colocas tu script en el tag **Head** comenzaran a cargar antes y puede darte problemas si lo que estas llamando se encuentra en el tag **Body**.

Para solucionar esto tienes varias opciones, tanto colocar el script al final del tag **Body** lo cual no esta mal, pero no es lo mas recomendado para una mejor optimización de carga.
Yo te recomendaría añadir el atributo **`defer`** en tu script.

Un ejemplo de como añadir el atributo **`defer`** a tu script:

```
<script src="assets/scripts/app.js" defer></script>
```

Esto hará que *el navegador "entienda" que debe descargar el script* en el orden en que esta colocado (tag "**HEAD**" en este caso), pero que *debe cargar este script después de acabar de cargar el código html*.

[Aquí tienes documentación sobre los atributos de Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/script)